# How to insert and get key value data in blob file(MYsql)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a scenerio where the user will insert data as key-value pair and i have to insert that data in Mysql db but in a column of BLOB type, later i have to do few operations with this data. For instance i have to store the below data in BLOB column, I am using JAVA spring, JDBC as back-end.

```
k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3,k4:v4 etc.....
```

I have to insert this data in Mysql table as a blob file, later i have to traverse it and append changes. How do i achieve it.
     For e.g: later i may change the value of k1 to m1 or even append new key value as "x1:v1".

Answer (score 0):

A `BLOB` type is meant to represent a large object (the L in bLob). Because of its size it usually not meant to be editable (by parts), but to be streamed. You don't normally insert it (or retrieve it) as a simple array of bytes, but by opening input and output streams to non-database sources/destinations that manage them.

You could easily exhaust the whole heap of your application by loading a single BLOB in memory.

In simple words, the editing of such a (big) value is usually handled outside the database, probably in your Java application.